# Active camera switched on me

Tags: camera

I had my active camera set up nicely and I have been working with it just fine.
I edited something in the scene and all of a sudden the active camera (Numpad 0) does not go back to my desired view. I assumed I must have done something accidentally to the camera. Instead of trying to fix it. I opened a backed up version, did a small edit, hit 0 and again, instead of my camera view, the camera window is empty.
What might have happened? And how do I get back to my original, desired view. It's important that I can rely on rendering the same angle of my map every time I do a render[image]

Comment: maybe you have some keyframe applied to the parent of the city scene. Check in the doopsheet turning "Only show Selected" off and "Show hidden" on, and remove any keyframes you find. [Screenshoot](https://imgur.com/a/n0XCbHG)

Comment: Also possible that you've set something else to be the active camera with ctrl-numpad 0. Select your camera in-scene and hit ctrl-numpad 0 just to be sure.